# What does Keras flow_from_directory return?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

```
image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255, horizontal_flip=True)

train_data_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, directory=train_dir, target_size=(IMG_SHAPE,IMG_SHAPE), shuffle=True)

augmented_images = [train_data_gen[0][0][0] for i in range(5)]
```

So I recently started looking into Tensorflow and was trying to create my own CNN, while looking at how to use ImageDataGenerator I came across this code.
I am wondering what does the .flow_from_directory return it seems to be iterable object of images. However what is confusing me is why train_data_gen has three dimensions, what do the dimensions mean.

Comment: Probably output's 3 dimensions represents (Batch_size,height,width).

Answer (score 2):

The train_data_gen is exactly that, a generator. In order to produce an output one needs to execute code

```
images, labels=next(train_data_gen)
```

the result is a batch_size number of images and their associated labels. Images
will have the shape(batch_size, IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE, channels) and labels are shape (batch_size,1).